# What's defference between AsyncTaskLoader and Loader?

Tags: android, android-loader

Cannot understand when I need to use `Loader` and when `AsyncTaskLoader`? I read docs by these class but I understood it badly. As I understood `Loader` allows to do a background work so it must be launched in non-GUI thread, it isn't? Why does `AsyncTaskLoader` do all same? I'm confused already.

Please, someone explain me more details.

Comment: Loader you could register receivers within and receive them, they live as long as the activity still running, while the asynctask is ended when its job is done.

Comment: I asked about `AsyncTaskLoader` and `Loader`. Just I cannot understand if `Loader` works in background why do we need the `AsyncTaskLoader`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the `Loader` methods are called on the main thread - **`Loader` does not do any work on a background thread**. This allows you to use whatever loading mechanism you want - be it a separate thread, callbacks to another component, or anything else.

`AsyncTaskLoader` extends `Loader` and adds [loadInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html#loadInBackground()), a method specifically called on a background thread. It is simply a convenience class for the simple case.

In either case, the *real* role of Loaders is to make loading data lifecycle aware as explained in [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832) - `Loader`s (and hence, `AsyncTaskLoaders`) survive configuration changes such as screen rotations. The blog contains a number of examples of `AsyncTaskLoader`, using an `AsyncTaskLoader` with an observer of changes, and a `Loader` which gets data from another data source using callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Then I realized it wrong in the root)